# Dynamically Selecting from a Table Variable in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I'm working with SQL Server and facing an issue with dynamic SQL in a stored procedure. My goal is to count the number of rows in a table, but the table name needs to be dynamically determined based on a variable.

```
DECLARE @varCount BIGINT
SELECT @varCount = COUNT(1)
FROM dbo.[table-staging]

IF(@varCount > 0)
BEGIN
    -- Other operations
END
```

In the above, dbo.[table-staging] is hardcoded, but I want to replace it with a variable, say @staging. I tried the following approach, but it doesn't seem to work:

`SET @varCount = 'SELECT @varCount = COUNT(1) FROM ' + @staging;`

Comment: No need for dynamic SQL at all; use a parametrised query against the system objects. [How to count the number of rows in a table in SQL Server](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/count-number-rows-table-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to store the result of dynamic SQL query in variable.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE CountRowsInTable
    @staging VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @varCount BIGINT;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = 'SELECT @varCount = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@staging);
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@varCount BIGINT OUTPUT', @varCount OUTPUT;

    SELECT @varCount;

    IF(@varCount > 0)
        BEGIN
            -- Other operations
        END;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use dynamic SQL at all here. Just use the system tables to get the rowcount for the table:

```sql
DECLARE @TableName sysname = N'table-staging';

DECLARE @RowCount bigint;

SELECT @RowCount = SUM(p.rows)
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.partitions p ON t.object_id = p.object_id
     JOIN sys.indexes i ON p.object_id = i.object_id
                       AND p.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE s.name = N'dbo' --YOu may want to parametrise this too
  AND t.name = @TableName
  AND i.index_id < 2;

IF @RowCount > 0 BEGIN
    ...
END;
```

If you don't actually need the value of the row count later, then you can put the query into a subquery in the `IF` instead, if you prefer.